# it is possible to make some wifi router out of service without have the connection password?

Tags: attacks, wifi, router

Lets say i want to make some WiFi router out of service. 
I can connect to the router and close the WiFi connection or change the password.

But in this case i need to have full access to the router.

But if i don't have access to the router ( i mean that i don't have password ) 
 ==> is it possible to damage it in such a way that disable the service.

Comment: You can jam the medium by sending random garbage noise, essentially increasing the signal to noise ratio to the point where the signals becomes unusable.

Comment: I am really surprised that no one has yet pointed out that causing harmful interference, whether physical or logical, is illegal in most countries...

Comment: These kinds of questions are strictly against StackExchange Terms of Service - see http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/928/16667 for a good explanation. Had he phrased it as a learning exercise, sure, but this phrasing is very suspicious and we shouldn't cater to the user unless he can completely quantify what he is trying to do and validate it as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deauthenticate users. 
With aireplay-ng this makes users disassociate with the router denying them the service

This with the option -0
So

```
Aireplay-ng
    -0 [how many packets you wannt to send] \
    -a [mac of ap] \
    -c [mac of client you want to deauthenticate] \
    [interface]
```

If you are associated to the network you could arp-spoof the clients to belive you are the router and just do whatever you want with the traffic

Answer (score 2):

If you are connected to the router you can do it with a DDOS attack if it doesn't have a firewall or it is disabled. On the other side a router normally drops malicious packets sent to it but if it doesn't have a performing CPU and you send a lot of them, it can't analyze all packets and a service disruption will happen. If you are not connected to the router you can deauthenticate all the clients with airodump-ng.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform an attack dos for a wifi AP ( you can do it through an android device too)

- You must be connected to the wifi (without access to the router)

1) Using an android device go to setting > Wifi > copy your adress wifi somehing like `192.168.0.108`

2) Forget the connection

3) Clic to connect to the wifi again , Do not type the password , You need to change the IP adress , Go to **Show advanced setting**

Go to IP setting and change **DHCP** to **Static** and type the **IP adress of the Router** Generally something like `192.168.0.1`  and **Connect**

**Any device connected to the router will be out of service**

Comment: but in this case i must have access to the router ( as you said ) and i talking about a case that i don't have the wifi login password ... so i can't connect to the wifi network

Comment: try this .. on my android ( galaxy s5 ) i don't find the DHCP possible. 
So i can't change the ip address of the router and connect.

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this.  All of them are illegal (in the US at least).

1. You can repeat traffic with a tiny bit of delay.  You can make a
   nice device to do this out of a router and a Raspberry pi, in
   theory, but you should not.  You can also just broadcast random
   noise, but echoes are worse.  This is because random noise acts
   Gaussian, which has less effect on capacity.  Echoes lead to more
   fading, which is harder on your channel capacity.
2. You can also hack your way onto the network using something like
   Wireshark/Kali.   This is more illegal, but possible.  The last
   phase of most of these exploits involve trying to join the network
   over and over, which bogs down the router for a long time.
3. You could also sneak over to the device and unplug it.  Classic
   strategies remain effective ones.

NOTE: I'm telling you these things are possible.  YOU SHOULD NOT DO THEM.